# whats wrong with this jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting syntax error in firebug here is the code :

```
$('#moderator-attention').live('toogle', function(){                  
             function () {
                $(".moderator-tex").show();
              },
              function () {
                $(".moderator-tex").hide();
              }

             });
```

I want to create a toogle function, when button is clicked then textarea with class `moderator-tex` should appear .. and if other button is clicked then should be hidden ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#moderator-attention').live('toogle', function(){                  
    $(".moderator-tex").slideToggle();
   }
});
```

If your textarea is not created on-the-fly, you can even try:

```
$('#moderator-attention').click(function(){                  
    $(".moderator-tex").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: What I meant to do is I have multiple radio buttons when one is checked textarea shows.. and if you choose any other it hides

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution: http://api.jquery.com/live/#multiple-events

And the syntax error occurs because you have something like this:

```
function() {
    function() {

    },
    function() {

    }
}
```

And this makes no sense.

Comment: What I meant to do is I have multiple radio buttons when one is checked textarea shows.. and if you choose any other it hides

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question/comments maybe you ought to try this :

```
    $("input:radio").click(function() {
        var value = $this("attr", "value");
        if(value == "expected value"){
        $(".moderator-tex").show();
       }else{
       $(".moderator-tex").hide();
       }

    });
```

You should set some value for this particular radio button to make this work

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#moderator-attention').live('toogle', function () {
  $('.moderator-text').toggle();
});
```

Would be how I would do it.

Not quite sure what you're trying to achieve doing it your way...